# Debugging Python Program LCM

Tags: python, debugging

So I have this program:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    while y % x != 0:
        y = y % x
        x = x % y
    return y
def lcm(x, y):
    (x * y) / gcd(x, y)
a = lcm(1, 2)
b = lcm(3, a)
c = lcm(b, 4)
d = lcm(5, c)
e = lcm(6, d)
f = lcm(e, 7)
g = lcm(f, 8)
h = lcm(9, g)
i = lcm(h, 10)
j = lcm(11, i)
k = lcm(12, j)
l = lcm(k, 13)
m = lcm(l, 14)
n = lcm(15, m)
o = lcm(n, 16)
p = lcm(17, o)
q = lcm(18, p)
r = lcm(q, 19)
print(lcm(r, 20))
```

Ok, so I've worked that one out now thanks to answers on this post, but why does this:

```
def gcd(x, y):
        while y % x != 0:
            y = y % x
            x = x % y
        return y
    def lcm(x, y):
        return (x * y) / gcd(x, y)
    a = lcm(1, 2)
    b = lcm(3, a)
    c = lcm(b, 4)
    d = lcm(5, c)
    e = lcm(6, d)
    f = lcm(e, 7)
    g = lcm(f, 8)
    h = lcm(9, g)
    i = lcm(h, 10)
    j = lcm(11, i)
    k = lcm(12, j)
    l = lcm(k, 13)
    m = lcm(l, 14)
    n = lcm(15, m)
    o = lcm(n, 16)
    p = lcm(17, o)
    q = lcm(18, p)
    r = lcm(q, 19)
    print(lcm(r, 20))
```

return this:

```
ZeroDivisonError: float modulo
```

Complaining about the second line, I gather I might need some sort of `if` statement to put the two numbers in order.
Anyone got any information about why this is happening?
Thanks.

Comment: By the way, a shortcut to solving this problem would be `functools.reduce(lcm, range(1, 21))`

Comment: If it's complaining about the second line then at some point `x == 0` and you're trying to `y % x` - that is `y % 0`, which would give the error.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `return` something in the `lcm` function.

```
def lcm(x, y):
    return (x * y) / gcd(x, y)
```

When you don't explicitly return anything in a function, Python automatically returns `None`. When you try `lcm(r, 20)`, that's the same as `lcm(None, 20)`, which doesn't work since you multiply both parameters in the `lcm` function - you can't do `None * 20`.

However this will yield another error - there's a problem with your `gcd` function as well!

The error comes when `y % x` is `0`, and then you do `x % y` straight after. This would be a working solution:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    while y != 0:
        x, y = y, x % y
    return x
```

This is taken straight from [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) from the Wikipedia article (Section 2.2).

Comment: Ok, but now it returns `ZeroDivisionError: float modulo`

Comment: @user2128561 well that's because your `gcd` function is messed up as well

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding here.when you use `gcd()` inside `lcm()`, you are creating nested environments. `gcd()`'s environment doesn't have access to the global environment.anything that it returns, will be accessible by `lcm()`'s environment.you don't return anything to the global environment in `lcm()`, so python by default returns `None`.to fix this try:

```
def lcm(x, y):
    return (x * y) / gcd(x, y)
```

also you have to add this block to the `lcm()` to avoid throwing `ZeroDivision` exception:

```
def lcm(x, y):
    try:
        return (x * y) / gcd(x, y)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        do whatever you want and return a value
```